# How to set dialog gravity programmatically?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am able to set `WRAP_CONTENT` in my layout's parameters, but how do I set `CENTER` gravity?

```
final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final RatingBar rating = new RatingBar(this);
    rating.setMax(5);
    rating.setRating(1);
    rating.setNumStars(5);
    popDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
    popDialog.setTitle("Vote!! ");
    popDialog.setView(rating);
    popDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    int rawrating = rating.getProgress();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    popDialog.create();
    popDialog.show();
    // force to set setNumStars
    rating.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

Comment: you wanna centre dialog position or dialog view?

Comment: I want to center RatingBar in my alertDialog

Comment: you can make a custom layout for alert dialog and in that custom layout you can set the gravity of your rating bar to whatever you want

Comment: check my updated answer @user8069029

Comment: @user8069029 awesome! You write question "How to set dialog gravity" and then it means that you need to center view **inside** dialog.

Comment: check my update ans my friend @user8069029

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
        Window window = dialog_card.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

try this it will help you.

**craete a custom view like this**

```
 <LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="vertical">
   <RatingBar
   android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:max="5"
   android:numStars="5"
   android:stepSize="1" />
</LinearLayout>

    final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    popDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
    popDialog.setTitle("Vote!! ");
    popDialog.setView(R.layout.custom);
    popDialog.setCancelable(false);
    LayoutInflater mlLayoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    final  View dialView=mlLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom,null);
    final RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) dialView.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
    AlertDialog dialog_card = popDialog.create();
    Window window = dialog_card.getWindow();

    window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


    popDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    int rawrating = ratingBar.getProgress();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Rating :-> " + rawrating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    });

    popDialog.show();
```